# Determine coefficients so that $f(x,y)$ is a conserved quantity

Tags: classical-mechanics

Given the function $f(x,y) = ax^2y + by + ct^2 $  with $x(t)=2t$ and $y(t)=3t^2$ I shall determine the coefficients a,b,c so that $f(x,y)$ is a conserved quantity.
My approach is
$$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$$
In the end, after substituting  $x$ and $y$, I get:
$$24at^3 + 6tb + ct = 0$$
How do I continue by now? $a=b=c=0$ probably isn't the intented solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you say you need that
$$
24at^3 + 3tb + ct = 0
$$
(with a small correction to your calculation)

Which for $t \neq 0 $ is the same that
$$
24at^2 + 3b + c = 0
$$
for all no zero $t$. But if $a \neq  0$ you have a polynomial in $t$, which have almost two root for given coeficients, so the equality can't hold for all t, which force us to take $a = 0$. Now we have:
$$
3b +c = 0 \implies c=-3b
$$
So $f$ is a conserved quantity if is of the form
$$
f(x,y) = by - 3 b t^2
$$